# Using google transliteration locally

Tags: javascript, google-translate

I am using this code below to use google transliteration facility in my site, I want to host this service in one intranet site which may not have internet access, how do i use this service ?

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAAIiziw8VGTxhqSejgYtAT8hTwfQc0k8B8CG-VP_1HP5Pa0SmTchSXi4Ra9nGkiQXIcDYFs648bUkc6A">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Google Transliterate API
      google.load("elements", "1", {
            packages: "transliteration"
          });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code:**

```
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Load the Google Transliterate API
    google.load("elements", "1", {
        packages: "transliteration"
    });
```

The code you just wrote for google-transliteration can not work in offline mode because the **`javascript API`** you are requesting from google servers works only when you are connected with `Google-transliteration` servers using internet.

I'll recommend this link for your offline support, If your website uses intranet on windows network you can visit

- http://www.google.com/inputtools/windows/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, you have to be able to connect to Google to use the service. It is not all contained in javascript, and requires Google's servers to work.